# Macro for different fonts for math and subscripts

Tags: math-mode, fonts, macros

Is it possible to define a macro which (in math mode) typesets normal math and subscripts in different fonts?

Concretely, I am interested in typesetting the math in roman and the subscripts in italic, such that

```
$\mymacro{A_pB_r}$
```

would result in

[image]

---

In response to an answer, let me clarify that the hope would be that this works on equal footing for a general parameter string (at least as long as it only includes characters and alphanumerical subscripts), such as $A_pB_r$, $ABC_s$, $A_xBC_y$, and so further.  Clearly, this can be broken down to individual letters with & without subscripts, but this would make the involved expressions extremely cumbersome and lengthy to type up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\mymacro#1{\mbox{$\textfont1=\textfont0 #1$}}

\begin{document}

$\mymacro{A_pB_r}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: This will break some things expecting to find the math italic font in slot 1, but ...

Comment: Cool, thanks!  How does it work? (Or rather: Where can I learn how it works? Seems pretty simple!)

Comment: ... Ah, guess I found it out! :)  Thanks again!

Comment: @Norbert TeXBook has the details of this (and other things). Is this for Chemistry? (in which case one of the dedicated chemistry packages would be better)

Comment: Cool, thanks (though reading 500 pages to understand how to do this sounds a bit intimidating :-/ ).  No, it's not for chemistry -- some self-cooked-up notation for physics/math.  Not even sure it will stay like that, which is one reason why I'd prefer a macro.

Answer (score 1):

The `unicode-math` package supports this through the `\setmathfont[script-font = ...]` option.  Here is a contrived example that sets the script font to XITS Math:

```
\documentclass[varwidth, preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmathfont[Scale = MatchLowercase,
             script-font = XITS Math
            ]{Latin Modern Math}

\begin{document}
\( t_x + \beta_\rho = b_a
\)
\end{document}
```

[image: Latin Modern Math, XITS scripts]

For comparison, using the default settings:

[image: Latin Modern Math]

According to §4.2 of the `unicode-math` manual, this is intended to be used with fonts such as Minion Math.  However, some families of text fonts package the smaller size as a different font, for example, to use Aldus as the script size for Palatino.

If your font comes with optical sizes but not mathematical script sizes, you would select those with `script-features` and `sscript-features`.

### ETA

It’s possible to change the math font in the middle of a document or to have more than one math version.  If you want to set only a few subscripts in a particular font, one way to do it is `_\text{...}`, then use text-mode font-selection commands inside the braces. Optionally wrap that in `\mathord{}` or `\mathop{}`, as appropriate.  If you do this more than once, make it a comamnd in your preamble.

Comment: Thanks!  Though I guess with will change it for *all* formulas, rather only for selected ones (which is what I am looking for).

Comment: @Norbert Added an addendum.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that? It's definitely not the best answer, but (at least) a proposal …

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\newcommand{\mycom}[2]{\mathrm{#1}_{#2}}
\begin{document}
    \Huge
    \[
        \mycom{A}{p} \ \mycom{B}{r}
    \]
\end{document}
```

Here is the output:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Ah, I should have been more specific: I don't know in which form the parameters will be passed -- some will have subscripts, some won't, and their number will also be different.  Would be good if I this could all be taken care of by one macro.